# Find gaps of a sequence in SQL without creating additional tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table `invoices` with a field `invoice_number`. This is what happens when i execute `select invoice_number from invoice`:

```
invoice_number
--------------
1
2
3
5
6
10
11
```

I want a SQL that gives me the following result:

```
gap_start | gap_end
4         | 4
7         | 9
```

How can i write a SQL to perform such query?
I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: I think you will find the `LEAD()` window function (or `LAG()`) very helpful.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The name of this problem is the "Gaps and Islands problem" which can be done with any [modern SQL](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2015-02/modern-sql), using [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select invoice_number + 1 as gap_start, 
       next_nr - 1 as gap_end
from (
  select invoice_number, 
         lead(invoice_number) over (order by invoice_number) as next_nr
  from invoices
) nr
where invoice_number + 1 <> next_nr;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1e807/1

Walkthrough example here using row_number over partition and interval: [Postgres Consecutive Days, gaps and islands, Tabibitosan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67529168/postgres-consecutive-days-gaps-and-islands-tabibitosan)

Answer (score 5):

We can use a simpler technique to get all missing values first, by joining on a generated sequence column like so:

```sql
select series
from generate_series(1, 11, 1) series
left join invoices on series = invoices.invoice_number
where invoice_number is null;
```

This gets us the series of missing numbers, which can be useful on it's own in some cases.

To get the gap start/end range, we can instead join the source table with itself.

```sql
select invoices.invoice_number + 1 as start, 
       min(fr.invoice_number) - 1 as stop
from invoices
left join invoices r on invoices.invoice_number = r.invoice_number - 1
left join invoices fr on invoices.invoice_number < fr.invoice_number
where r.invoice_number is null
      and fr.invoice_number is not null
group by invoices.invoice_number,
         r.invoice_number;
```

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=32c5f3c021b0f1a876305a2bd3afafc9

This is probably less optimised than the above solutions, but could be useful in SQL servers that don't support `lead()` function perhaps.

---

Full credit goes to this excellent page in SILOTA docs:
http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-gap-analysis-missing-values-sequence.html

I highly recommend reading it, as it explains the solution step by step.

Answer (score 1):

I found another query:

```
 select invoice_number + lag gap_start, 
        invoice_number + lead - 1 gap_end
    from (select invoice_number, 
                 invoice_number - lag(invoice_number) over w lag,
                 lead(invoice_number) over w - invoice_number lead 
              from invoices window w as (order by invoice_number)) x 
  where lag = 1 and lead > 1;
```