# Find gaps of a sequence in PostgreSQL tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table invoices with a field invoice_number. This is what happens when i execute select invoice_number from invoice

| invoice_number |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 10 |
| 11 |

I want a SQL that gives me the following result:

| gap_start | gap_end |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 10 | 11 |

Comment: You should not use a sequence for invoice numbers, it's normal for a sequence to have "gaps".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find gaps of a sequence in SQL without creating additional tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168418/find-gaps-of-a-sequence-in-sql-without-creating-additional-tables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9faffb7b5d11f826ac7367d584c3b537)

You can use [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to create a row count and use the difference to your actual values as group criterion:

```
SELECT
    MIN(invoice) AS start,
    MAX(invoice) AS end
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        invoice - row_number() OVER (ORDER BY invoice) as group_id
    FROM t
) s
GROUP BY group_id
ORDER BY start
```