# Select values that are not present in a postgres column (without upper limit)

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands

Given a postgres table foo that contains an `external_id BIGINT` column which has some gaps. Is there a way, without looping or using an excessively large `generate_sequence` to `exclude` from or `join` against, to get `n` values that are not present in said column?

Let's say it has rows with external_ids `1, 3, 5, 7` and I want it to return `5` sequential values, it should return `2, 4, 6, 8, 9`. The next select (given that nothing changed) should return `10, 11, 12, 13, 14` etc. So both gaps and continuously rising, sequential ids should be returned. I could do something like

```sql
WITH
  id_series AS (
    SELECT
      generate_series(1, 10) AS ids
  )
SELECT
  id_series.ids
FROM
  id_series
  left join known_ids ki on id_series.ids = kid.id
where
  ki.id is null
limit 5;
```

this however might not return enough unused ids if the sequence isn't big enough for it to find unused ones, having to loop for as long as 5 ids have been returned.

My table currently contains ids ranging between 50,000 and 1,800,000,000. Some gaps are a few million ids wide, some others ranges don't have a gap for another few millions (potentially requiring to loop many many times or using a very large sequence)

Is there any clever & efficient way to solve this?

---

Here's the reason I'm doing this. The table contains the `external_ids` from an external data source. this data source has to be queried with individual ids. the data source exposes its entities over time. so id 1 billion might be "public" before id 5. so I need to know for which external ids I didn't get a response YET and query them periodically. As I said before, it's something I can't change because I don't control the external data source. It's an actual business requirement I cannot change.

Comment: Any number of reasons why this might not be feasible--depends on why you have gaps and how they get filled--but have you considered building a table containing the list of "gap" Ids, and then picking/deleting from there to fill in the gaps? It'd take the "big query" to fill, but once done it's done.

Comment: The most effective/efficient solution is **do nothing, it is not a problem**. Accept that gaps are normal and expected. Also consider the column name `external_id` implies you do not control the value. So why are you manufacturing values? Further, if you are generating the values, it is still not a problem. Starting the highest value you current have  (1,800,000,000) and you generate 1,000,000 values per second then you have 290,000 years before you exceed the maximum for a bigint.

Comment: because I need to know the gaps and query the external source for the gaps periodically @Belayer it's not a matter of data hygiene and the gaps are not a "problem", they simply are part of my problem domain

Comment: What is actually the problem? I see that in the range 1, 3, 5 there are no numbers 2 and 4, but I don't see the problem. The numbers 1.1 and 2.8 are also not there. And "id" stands for "identifier" and the number 1 does the same job as number 3, even when number 2 is not there.

Comment: see my comment above. the table contains the external_ids from an external data source. this data source has to be queried with individual ids. the data source exposes its entities over time. so id 1 billion might be "public" before id 5. so i need to know for which external ids i didn't get a response YET and query them periodically. as i said before, it's something i can't change because I don't control the external data source. I'm not doing this for fun but because it's an actual business requirement.

Comment: @PhilipKelley In that case, as Philip suggested, also keep a table with the ids (or id ranges) that are still missing and that you want to query. Store for each range when it was last queried, what the response was, and when it should be scanned next. When you do get a response, delete/split the range to remove those where you found an entity.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has to scan the entire table anyway. I don't think it would be too inefficient to use something like

```
SELECT generate_series(
  (SELECT MIN(external_id) FROM known),
  (SELECT MAX(external_id) FROM known)
)
EXCEPT
SELECT external_id FROM known
```

Sure, this will not return ids below or above the existing ids, and might generate less ids than the `n` values you need, but you could easily handle that in your application logic. Or use `generate_series(1, max(external_id)+n)`.

If you don't actually need individual ids, but rather the range of each gap, look into [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) queries such as [Find gaps of a sequence in SQL without creating additional tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30168418/1048572).

If you don't need all gaps at once, but only the next ones, with no more than `n` values, you can write an iterative algorithm to find gap after gap (until you have enough values) using a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE).

Comment: `EXCEPT` is super slow for me, however, a left join where nothing is found in the known table is crazy fast when used with a limit (which is fine because I'm querying in batches anyways and don't need all ids at once). I guess because generate_series is lazy enough. It only gets slow when an offset is used but this can be worked around by doing the offset via the lower bound of the generate_series call. IDK why I was under the impression that this would be slow.. 

Thanks for actually giving an answer :)